# Making variables global i iAd Producer

Tags: javascript, iad

sorry if this is a really simple question. Still, I am stuck:

I would like to have widgets access other widget's variables. I would have thought, for instance, that it would be possible to declare a variable

```
var Utility = this.viewController.outlets.Utility;
```

in Global.js, refering to a widget declared in one of the standard auxiliary (.js) files.

I assume that there are more clever ways of doing this. I'm not new to programming, but I'm new to both iAd Producer and JavaScript.

Any and all pointers welcome.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is to have other files access information about the current widget?  If that is the case you would se up a NSObject subclass and then have properties that are declared in the .h file so that other parts of your code can access them and see what there values are. So for instance if you had a class called person you would have some properties like this.

```
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *lastName
    @property (nonatomic) int age;
```

Then if you have a person object in another file and you want to get information out of them you would do this.

```
    Person *p = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *personsName = p.name;
```

let me know if that makes sense or you need more info!